# LastPass extension - cannot login

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, add-on

Mac OS X High Sierra - TorBrowser 7.5.6 (based on Mozilla Firefox 52.9.0)
I cannot use LastPass because the login window will not popup from the top window menu (the black square with three dots).
I tried unblocking popups, which unfortunately didn't help.

What should I do?

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 10, Tor Browser version 7.5.6. When I click other extensions (e.g., HTTPS Everywhere), I get a drop-down menu. With Lastpass, I can see a triangle, but the drop-down menu looks like it's covered by the page display. I assume this is a bug, but I'm looking for any suggestions before reporting it. I'd also like confirmation that others are experiencing this problem. Today is day 1 with the Tor Browser for me. If I can't use Lastpass, then it severely hinders using the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely the cause of some Tor browser specific security/privacy reinforcements.

Anyways, you shouldn't install additional addons in Tor browser since this can deanonymize you.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. What I did was temporarily disconnect from tor bridge, login to lastpass account and then again connect to tor bridge.